# Is there any documentation for posing nude models?

Tags: lighting, nude-photography

I am only a hobbyist and my partner and I are trying to get into nude photography. Are there any sources that have information on the basics of nude photography, such as poses, lighting, reducing body marks and improving the eroticism of the shot?

Poses are a big issue, as our studio is quite small, and we are trying to include props such as beds and tables. Angles are slightly more basic, but any information would be useful.

Are there any books or websites on this subject?

Comment: Tons of them. Have you tried Google?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Are there any books or websites on this subject?

Yes. Tons of them.

http://www.editorialnudes.com/ contains resources pointing to workshops, books, and online material.

[Darwin Wiggett](http://darwinwiggett.wordpress.com/tag/fine-art-nude-photography/) has some resources regarding fine art nudes at his site. Some of his work is studio, some is outdoor environmental portraits.

[Ed Verosky](http://www.edverosky.net/blog/2013/09/best-photography-instruction-of-2013/) is another source with links to instructional guides.

Several of the [*Glamour & Nude* titles](http://www.camerabooks.com/Departments/Glamour-and-Nude-Books/Glamour-and-Nude-How-to-Photography-Books-and-Tutorial-DVDs-%28New%29.aspx) at CameraBooks.com concentrate specifically on lighting.

Here is a [link to one title](http://books.google.com/books/about/The_Art_of_Nude_Photography.html?id=dhZ3AAAACAAJ) with many other related titles including some that concentrate on lighting, posing, and even one named 'Erotic Home Photography'.

Digital Camera World has this [online guide](http://www.digitalcameraworld.com/2011/04/12/fine-art-nude-photography-guide-tips-techniques-and-free-pdf/).

Even Digital Photography School has [at least one article](http://digital-photography-school.com/9-nude-photography-tips) about doing nudes.

Any web search for 'fine art nude photography instruction', or 'glamour and nude photography books', 'boudoir photo guide', or similar terms will reveal almost countless resources.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for your help.

Comment: but don't be alarmed to find a decent selection of porn sites (including some rather disturbing ones that misrepresent themselves to search engines deliberately) in your google results.

Comment: Including "fine art" in the search helps to cut out a lot of the porn links. I didn't see a porn site in any of the links I researched using 'fine art nude photography instruction'. There were a few links to books for sale on e-Bay that might be considered pornographic.

Comment: maybe you got lucky, or I consider things pornographic that you don't :) Not that I'm squeamish about it, mind (and some soft porn sites that turn up have pretty good photos among the less tasteful ones).

Comment: if you have an android phone (i think this app is also on iphone), here is a good app for ideas.
[link]https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lv.mendo.posingapp